# Export a mesh from a Unity webGL app and associate it with an AR.js maker

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar.js

*First of all, I am aware of the existence of the AR.js_Unity project and of the fact that we currently cannot (yet?) build a webGL app with AR component, from Unity.*

---

That being said, my problem is that I need to create a webGL application, using Unity. Basically, the app would be a 3D configurator. The user could apply some predefined textures to a specific area of a mesh (changing the label's texture of a bottle, for example). The user would also have the choice to either download the modified mesh or, and that's the point of that thread, display the customized mesh as an AR object through the browser.

Would it be possible to store the customized mesh in a database, and then use it with AR.js to display it through the browser?

**The scenario I have in mind is the following**

The user access to the webGL app, select a mesh and customize it, then click on an "augmented reality" button. At this very moment, the selected model is sent to a database, while a new tab open itself in the (mobile) web browser, launching the camera via AR.js ...

At this point, I am looking for a way to associate either a custom AR.js marker or a generated and AR.js approved QR code, with the customized mesh saved in the database. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do what you're trying to do.

Your best bet is to transfer your configuration options to a backend server, which applies the options to a model retrieved by AR.js.

Comment: Humf, and this seems to be waaay out of reach considering my skill ...
I am keeping the investigations "on " ...